Debezium DB2 Connector with apache camel generic Null error
I have created new IBM DB2 and I am trying to use it with Apache Camel Debezium DB2 Connector for CDC.
Here's my code:
@Component
public class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("debezium-db2:foo?" +
                "databaseHostName={{debezium-db2.databaseHostName}}" +
                "&databasePort={{debezium-db2.databasePort}" +
                "&databaseUser={{debezium-db2.databaseUser}}" +
                "&databasePassword={{debezium-db2.databasePassword}}" +
                "&offsetStorageFileName=./src/main/resources/offset.dat" +
                "&databaseDbname={{debezium-db2.databaseDbname}}" +
                "&topicPrefix=test").
                log("Event received from Debezium : ${body}");
    }
}

This is my Maven for Debezium:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-debezium-db2</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>

Here's the output:
....
....

2024-08-04T06:26:39.418+03:00 ERROR 2756 --- [ebeziumConsumer] io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine      : null


I tried to change the Query Parameters in the code and I tried change the maven and downgrade and upgrade.
